# How to safely switch from vim-athena to vim-gtk?

Tags: gvim, linux-ubuntu, x11

I have vim 7.4 Huge version with X11-Athena GUI installed on my laptop running ubuntu 16.04. I would like to safely switch to vim-gtk.

Do I have to uninstall existing vim installation and install vim-gtk from scratch, or is there a better way to achieve the same?

**Update:** 
I have installed `vim-gtk3`. Following are some additional information regarding my setup:

1. I have compiled vim from source, and `vim --version` returns the output appended below

> VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Jan  4 2016 01:01:13)
>   Huge version with X11-Athena GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
>   +arabic          +file_in_path    +mouse_sgr       +tag_binary
>   +autocmd         +find_in_path    -mouse_sysmouse  +tag_old_static
>   +balloon_eval    +float           +mouse_urxvt     -tag_any_white
>   +browse          +folding         +mouse_xterm     -tcl
>   ++builtin_terms  -footer          +multi_byte      +terminfo
>   +byte_offset     +fork()          +multi_lang      +termresponse
>   +cindent         +gettext         -mzscheme        +textobjects
>   +clientserver    -hangul_input    +netbeans_intg   +title
>   +clipboard       +iconv           +path_extra      +toolbar
>   +cmdline_compl   +insert_expand   -perl            +user_commands
>   +cmdline_hist    +jumplist        +persistent_undo +vertsplit
>   +cmdline_info    +keymap          +postscript      +virtualedit
>   +comments        +langmap         +printer         +visual
>   +conceal         +libcall         +profile         +visualextra
>   +cryptv          +linebreak       +python          +viminfo
>   +cscope          +lispindent      -python3         +vreplace
>   +cursorbind      +listcmds        +quickfix        +wildignore
>   +cursorshape     +localmap        +reltime         +wildmenu
>   +dialog_con_gui  -lua             +rightleft       +windows
>   +diff            +menu            -ruby            +writebackup
>   +digraphs        +mksession       +scrollbind      +X11
>   -dnd             +modify_fname    +signs           +xfontset
>   -ebcdic          +mouse           +smartindent     +xim
>   +emacs_tags      +mouseshape      -sniff           +xsmp_interact
>   +eval            +mouse_dec       +startuptime     +xterm_clipboard
>   +ex_extra        -mouse_gpm       +statusline      -xterm_save
>   +extra_search    -mouse_jsbterm   -sun_workshop
>   +farsi           +mouse_netterm   +syntax
>      system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
>        user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
>    2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
>         user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
>     system gvimrc file: "$VIM/gvimrc"
>       user gvimrc file: "$HOME/.gvimrc"
>   2nd user gvimrc file: "~/.vim/gvimrc"
>       system menu file: "$VIMRUNTIME/menu.vim"
>     fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/local/share/vim"
>   Compilation: gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_ATHENA   -I/usr/local/include  -g -O2 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1
>   Linking: gcc   -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,--as-needed -o vim -lXaw -lXmu -lXext -lXt -lSM -lICE -lXpm -lXt -lX11 -lXdmcp -lSM -lICE -ldl  -lm -ltinfo -lnsl   -ldl    -L/usr/lib/python2.7 -lpython2.7

2. `update-alternatives --display vim` returns

> vim - auto mode
>     link best version is /usr/bin/vim.gtk3
>     link currently points to /usr/bin/vim.gtk3
>     link vim is /usr/bin/vim
>   /usr/bin/vim.gtk3 - priority 50

3. `update-alternatives --display gvim` returns

   > gvim - auto mode
   >   link best version is /usr/bin/vim.gtk3
   >   link currently points to /usr/bin/vim.gtk3
   >   link gvim is /usr/bin/gvim
   >   /usr/bin/vim.gtk3 - priority 50

gvim continues to launch vim in Athena gui.

Comment: If you're building from source, then why do you have the system packages installed?  Either use the version you built from source or use the system packages.

Answer (score 4):

You don't have to uninstall any of the existing packages.  The vim-{athena,gtk,gtk3,nox} etc. packages just provide the Vim binary built with different feature sets and linked against different GUI toolkits.

1. Install the `vim-gtk` (or on newer systems `vim-gtk3`) package
2. Check whether the `vim` and `gvim` alternatives automatically switched to using `/usr/bin/vim.gtk` (or `/usr/bin/vim.gtk3`).  Note: this should be the case if you haven't manually set priorities on the alternatives.

   1. `$ update-alternatives --display vim`
   2. If you want to change the alternative, run `update-alternatives --config vim`
   3. Repeat for gvim

Comment: I have installed `vim-gtk3`, running `update-alternatives --config gvim`, I get "There is only one alternative in link group gvim (providing /usr/bin/gvim): /usr/bin/vim.gtk3 Nothing to configure." Running gvim launches the old athena vim gui

Comment: @ImranAli Then you have something preventing you from using the system-installed vim.  See what `which gvim` or `type gvim` report from your shell.

Comment: `which gvim` returns `/usr/local/bin/gvim` and `type gvim` returns `gvim is hashed (/usr/local/bin/gvim)`

Comment: Right. Your install to /usr/local is being used instead of the system's. You'll need to figure out which you want to use and move on from there.